# How to target nested XML data in order to update firebase

Tags: javascript, xml

Below is some XML for baseball scoring I am getting from an API. 
I am having issues grabbing individual innings by number and then getting the score (runs).

```
   <scoring>
      <inning number="1" sequence="1" runs="2"/>
      <inning number="2" sequence="2" runs="1"/>
    </scoring>
```

I tried doing an if statement to check if the inning number was 1 or 2 etc... but am struggling with that.

```
updates['/game/' + uid + '/homeTeamInningScore/1st'] = scoring.inning ?????;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could try Jquery $.grep and $.attr :

```
function getInningRuns( xmlString, inningNumber) {

            // parse xml string into xml nodes of type inning
            // if xml is not received as a string, you can omit the $.parseXML()
            var innings = $($.parseXML( xmlString )).find("inning"); 

            // get requested inning
            var inning = $.grep(innings, function(inning){
                              return ($(inning).attr("number") == inningNumber);
                         })[0];

            // return runs attribute
            return $(inning).attr("runs");
        }
```